# genymotion failed to flash (Gapps name).zip archive for an unknown reason

Tags: google-maps, android-studio, genymotion

I'm trying to install Gapps on a genymotion emulator (android 7.0) after flashing ARM Translation Installer v1.1 and then rebooting the device.
But I see this error after trying to install it every time:

> genymotion failed to flash (Gapps name).zip archive for an unknown
>   reason.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: and there are a lot of versions of the Gapp for any android api such as Mini_Dynamic_GApps     or    open_gapps-arm for android 7.0.                      what's the diffrence between them?

Answer (score 6):

If you have a recent enough version of Genymotion (>= 2.11), you can directly install the GApps through the OpenGApps button in the top-right corner of the window. This will work without installing ARM translations.

Answer (score 4):

As according to **@Aurélien Gâteau** & **@JalalJaberi** [see responses]

Latest version of Genymotion = GApps with GApps button as per below image link [Linux Version]

[image: open_gapps_for_gennymotion]

Comment: Welcome to SO and answering for the first time. I understand that the emulator works for you. It would be helpful if you try to understand the user's problem and suggest ways to fix the issue on their side. Maybe specifying the exact Gapp version might help them because from their comment they seem to not know the differences in different versions. Enjoy SO.

Answer (score 0):

NO NEED to download ARM or GAPPS separately. Genymotion have an option to automatically detect and download which version GAPPS is perfect.

```
CHECK RIGHT TOP CORNER IN GENYMOTION. THERE IS GAPPS OPTIONS!
```